# Image flipping using php

Tags: php, php-gd

I am provided with a hosting plan with php gd version 2 and I cannot install any other library. I know image flipping can be done by using imagesx() imagesy() and imagecreatetruecolor() but they are not available in  GD version 2. and I cannot upgrade to higher version. 
 So, is there any other way to flip image horizontally and vertically using php gd version 2 or just with php?  Thanks millions.

Comment: Most likely won't help your specific case, but you can flip an image using CSS in pretty much every browser: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/flip-an-image/ .

Comment: @RichBradshaw thanks a lot but can new image flipped by CSS saved in server? I am quite new to CSS. Thanks.

Comment: No, but sometimes that's OK, depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help... you will need to modify it to flip vertical though...

```
$size_x = imagesx($img);
$size_y = imagesy($img);

$temp = imagecreatetruecolor($size_x, $size_y);

imagecolortransparent($temp, imagecolorallocate($temp, 0, 0, 0));
imagealphablending($temp, false);
imagesavealpha($temp, true);
$x = imagecopyresampled($temp, $img, 0, 0, ($size_x-1), 0, $size_x, $size_y, 0-$size_x, $size_y);
if ($x) {
    $img = $temp;
}
else {
    die("Unable to flip image");
}

header("Content-type: image/gif");
imagegif($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Credit to [Markus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2490/markus): [Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66518/flip-an-image-horizontally)